# My Java program for removing special characters and white space from user input of name fails when I test it with spaces

Tags: java

I'm a student and am working on an assignment that has us trying a few techniques we haven't covered. Removing special characters and spaces from user input, I figured out how to remove the special characters but when I insert a space in my name when I try my program, my name is returned to me missing whatever letters were after the space. Like, "Pat ricia" becomes "Pat". I had to go with a different technique for removing special characters because "replaceAll" didn't work for me there, and it isn't working for me with removing white space. Can I have another set of eyes to tell me what I'm missing?

```
package edu.gmc.Course_Project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input_Name {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    //asking for user input
        
    System.out.print("enter your name: ");
    String name = scan.next();
        
    //Java won't do all this at once (2 step process) so I'm converting the whole name to lower case first
    
    name=name.toLowerCase();
    
    //now to get the first character 
    
    char first=name.charAt(0);
    
    //and changing it to upper case
    
    first=Character.toUpperCase(first);
        
    String newName="";
    newName+=first;
        
    //I'm not really sure about this part, but it has to do with the length...without it, my name was returned to me as "P"
    
    for(int i=1;i<name.length();i++)
    
    {
    //this part ignores anything other than A-Z or a-z...I had a different method earlier but I couldn't get it to work properly
        
    char ch=name.charAt(i);
        if(ch>='a' && ch<='z')
            {
                newName+=ch;
            }
        }
    
    //removing white spaces
    
    newName = newName.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        
    //the program is complete, now what does it do?
    
    System.out.println("your name is "+newName);
    
        
        
        
    
    }
}
```

Comment: by default scanner splits all input on whitespace, which is why you receive only "pat" for scan.next() - try using scan.nextLine() instead to fetch the whole input

Comment: Oh. That makes sense! We haven't gone over that either...nothing like lessons like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your program was not working was because you was using `String name = scan.next();` at the very start of your program, this command will store the next string inputted, and because there is a space it is simply storing the first string before the space, instead you need to use `String name = scan.nextLine();` as it will store the entire line including white space and additional strings,